# How can I prove this with induction?

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

Being $p,\,m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p>m\ge1$ and $p$ is not a multiple of $m$. How can I show that there are $q,\,r\in\mathbb{N}$ with $r<m$ such that $p=m\cdot q+r$? We take $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Okay, for $m\geq 1$ the statement holds, but is it possible that $m=1,p\in\mathbb N\;\land\; m\nmid p$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: This is exactly what the theorem of existence and uniqueness of division in $\mathbb{N}$ states.

Comment: It was only this in the statement of the question. There aren't any more information given. And I only put this title on the question because I didn't know how I could summarize this.

Comment: I saw your [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31220) and came here to say that, my guess for why people downvoted (and some voted to close) this question is because the post didn't demonstrate your own thoughts or efforts. I'm NOT saying that you didn't make an effort, I'm saying that the post doesn't show that. The "closing message" about "needing details or context" is an umbrella statement that is meant to cover a wide variety of reasons. In practice, most prominently, posts are often closed due to lack of effort ***shown***.

Comment: Anyway, I'm sorry about you getting downvotes. It feels really bad. Please don't be frustrated so as to cease trying to make good use this site.

Comment: @Lee I didn't show my on thoughts because when I posted I didn't have any idea of what use in this. So what was I suposed to put?

Comment: Anyway, with one downvote and a comment, it would already pass the massage. It was unnecessary 3 downvotes.

Comment: Just two quick points (1) The StackExchange community (the users) is actually rather _violently_ divided on many issues, including how/when to downvote questions. (2) As for what to say when one "has no clue", maybe in this case you can demonstrate some test calculations for a couple of small $m, q$ and $r$ (plus maybe another set of larger $m,q,r$) that are "easy numbers", while fixing $p$ to be also a nice number.

Comment: In general, what can be demonstrated will vary greatly from problems to problems, but basically any guess or hunch will be fine. The point is not for you to report any solid conclusions, the point is to show that you actually tried.

Answer (score 1):

Induct on $p\ge m+1$. For the base case $p=m+1$ take $q=1,\,r=1$. If $p=mq+r$, either $r=m-1$ so write $p+1=(m+1)q+0$, or else write $p+1=mq+(r+1)$.